# JIRA rest API to fetch board using only board name

Tags: java, jira, jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api

I am working on speech-to-text application which is based on Java. In which I need to create a JIRA ticket in a particular board. For this I have only board name available as a input. So what I am looking for is there any JIRA rest-api available through which I can fetch that particular board and can create a JIRA ticket in it if not is there any work-around so that I can create ticket in that particular board, which user is expecting.

Comment: Why is this tagged as `javascript` (besides the fact that this is way too broad and doesn't show any research effort)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [get all boards](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/software/rest/#api-board-get) resource to fetch all boards on the instance and filter the one you need by name. 
However, it's not possible to easily "create a ticket in a particular board". You can create an issue in a project, assigned to an epic but not to the board. Boards in Jira are based on JQL query (the basic boards are project boards, with JQL for a single project), but the issues that will appear on a board are dependent on the JQL query, so to create an issue in a particular board you need to create this issue in such a way that it will match the JQL query this board is assigned to (can be any JQL query user write). For example, if a user creates a board based on JQL: "component = ABC" then the issue you need to create needs a component value set to "ABC", otherwise it will not appear on the board.
Supporting all possible options and configurations of JQL is very hard and time-consuming, I suggest you support only project based boards, then you can use [get projects of board](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/software/rest/#api-board-boardId-project-get) resource to find the project (should be only one) assigned to the board (you already have the ID of board from [get all boards](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/software/rest/#api-board-get) resource) and simply create an issue in that project (it should appear on a board).